# Using reflection to create a menu in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

I am trying to create a menu using a WPF TreeView control. To that end, I have created an Interface that does nothing but expose a couple of Read Only properties (One item for the menu header, and one for the actual menu item) that I can bind the TreeView control to.

Each ViewModel I create will implement this interface, and the values for both properties will be hard coded in the getter of the property.

Is it possible to use reflection to get the values for these properties (before they are instantiated), and put them into some form of list or array that my TreeView control can then bind to?

The aim is to not have to hard code all the menu items to the TreeView, but have the control populated with all the ViewModels I have so far written (ie, each time a viewmodel is created it will just "appear" in the menu, after recompiling the assembly of course!).

I can obtain the names of the classes implimenting the interface by using:

```
foreach (Type mytype in System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
              .Where(mytype => mytype.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IInterfaceName))))
        {
            c.Add(mytype);

        }
```

This code works to get the names of the classes implementing the interface, but after this I get stuck.

Is what I am trying to do even possible?  If I am not on the right track, I would also appreciate any other ways to achieve the same results.  I do not want to hard code values in the WPF, nor do I want to have to add records to a database when I create a new viewmodel.

Here is a mock up of what I am trying to create:
[Mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsnAI.png)

Comment: `to get the values for these properties (before they are instantiated)` does'nt make sense, how can you get propertie values of a null reference

Comment: Im confused by the word 'Menu' do you mean context menu for the nodes?

Comment: @MichaelRandall - By "Menu", I mean using a TreeView control with each 'node' on the tree being a header menu which groups common functionality (sort of like a standard Windows/Winforms Edit menu, where "Edit" is the node, and then "Copy", "Cut" and "Paste" are all child nodes. I understand what you are saying about not instantiating the classes... maybe I'm taking an incorrect approach. I'm relatively new to OOP and self-taught (my original degree in programming was in COBOL).

Comment: @GrantWinney - My Interface code is:
interface IMyInterface
    {
            string MenuHeader
            {
                get;
            }
            string MenuItemName
            {
                get;
            }
     }

And ViewModel code is:
class MenuOneItemOne : IMyInterface
    {
        public string MenuHeader
        {
            get
            {
                return "Header 1";
            }
        }
        public string MenuItemName
        {
            get      {
                return "Item 1";
            }
        }
    }

Comment: I'm not even sure this approach will work... What I am trying to avoid is having to manually "hard code" a menu structure. I thought I could get the menu items to appear by adding a view/viewmodel pair to my assembly, but once again, also very new to the MVVM pattern...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend looking into [Managed Extensibility Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/)  (MEF). MVVM and MEF fit really well together since the goal of MVVM is ultimately decoupling separate concerns, and MEF is technology that makes loose coupling very easy. MVVM is concerned with decoupling separate layers, but there is also an advantage to decoupling different views models from each other (which is basically what you are asking for). Here's a very basic example of how to get started using MEF to implement your particular question.

First you need to make an interface for the sub-view models:

```
public interface ISubViewModel
{
    string Name { get; }
    IView View { get; }
    //... whatever else you need
}
```

Now, you'll have some sort of parent or master view:

```
[Export]
public class ParentViewModel
{
    [ImportMany] // <- this attribute tells MEF to look for all exports of type ISubViewModel
    public IEnumerable<ISubViewModel> ViewModels { get; set; }

    //... whatever else you need
}
```

Now you can simply delcare as many sub view models as you like, they will all automatically show up in the ViewModels property of ParentViewModel:

```
[Export(typeof(ISubViewModel))]
public class MySubViewModel1 : ISubViewModel { /* ... */ }

[Export(typeof(ISubViewModel))]
public class MySubViewModel2 : ISubViewModel { /* ... */ }

[Export(typeof(ISubViewModel))]
public class MySubViewModel3 : ISubViewModel { /* ... */ }
```

The only thing left is to setup the MEF container. For the `[ImportMany]` attribute to work in the `ParentViewModel`, we have to let MEF construct it. We'll setup the container and ask it for a `ParentViewModel` (perhaps this would go in your App.xaml.cs)

```
public void Startup()
{
    var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();  
    catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
    var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
    var parentViewModel = container.GetExportedValue<ParentViewModel>();
    parentViewModel.Show();
}
```

Behind the scenes, MEF is basically using reflection in the same way you are trying to in your example, but MEF makes it much easier and hides all the reflection ugliness from you, all you have to do is add the appropriate `[Import]` and `[Export]` attributes.

Using MEF is a bit like async/await in the way it tends to "invade" your entire code base. Any class you make can use `[Import]` or `[ImportMany]` (or also constructor injection, see docs), as long as it is `[Export]`-ed and instances of it are retrieved by MEF. For a good example of a complete MVVM style application using MEF, have a look at the [WAF](https://github.com/jbe2277/waf) examples (there are other MVVM frameworks that make use of MEF or some other sort of DI, but I'm personally most familiar with WAF).

The result of using MEF like this throughout your application will be an extremely modular and loosely coupled application, which happens to be absolutely terrific for testability.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  MEF looks like it is designed to achieve exactly what I am trying to accomplish. I will look at it much more closely.